# JavaScript : Issue in Function being called from one Js file to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am working with `ASP.net` and `JQuery`.
In one Aspx page i have many Js pages included.
Now i added one more Js file(say `page1.js`) and i was calling a function from `page1.js` to another js file(`page2.js`) which was also included in the same Aspx page.

When i tried calling the method(`Page1Func`) from `page2.js` i was getting undefined error message.

ASPX Page:

```
  <script src="<%= SomeCommonFunc.GetResolvedUrl("~/Page1.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="<%= SomeCommonFunc.GetResolvedUrl("~/Page2.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Page1.js

```
function page1Func(){
   //Some code
}
```

Page2.js

```
function page2Func(){
   //Some code
   page1Func(); // giving undefined error message
}
```

so i did this:

```
function page2Func(){
    var someFunc = Page1Func; //it worked
    someFunc();
}
```

And it worked.I'm not sure why this message was coming.i have also tried to change the order to include of Js file in ASPX page.
it would be great if someone can help me in explaining this behavior.

P.S : I have checked on internet and didn't get the proper answer for it.

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to show us how you imported those files, and what the functions look like. Perhaps you load them synchronously and sometimes one is not loaded before the other.

Comment: Hi @Randy , I'm not suppose to upload the code.however i did tried to change the order in which Js files were included.it didn't work.And strangely the Page1Func() was getting called in somewhere and getting undefined at some place.Please guide me if i m missing something. thanks

Comment: Hi @Randy i have updated my question,hope it is helpful to understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

The function could be called as if it was in the same JS File as long as the file containing the definition of the function has being loaded before the first use of the function.

I.e.

File1.js

```
function alertNumber(number) {
    alert(number);
}
```

File2.js

```
function alertOne() {
     alertNumber("one");
}
```

HTML

```
<head>
....
    <script src="File1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="File2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
....
</head>
<body>
....
    <script type="text/javascript">
       alertOne();
    </script>
....
</body>
```

If your code is something like this then there is no chance of giving undefined at all

Here is [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7zTTcMEjnkixVboAs4ag?p=preview) implementation

Comment: Hi @raVan96, I appreciate your efforts to answer my question,but it still dosnt give me justified explanation. i have updated my question.please look into it and give your input if possible.